# Thread permissions in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, permissions

I'm launching a lengthy import on a new thread in an ASP.NET page.

Everything is working fine *except* that I get a failed IO permission when I try to write to my log file from the worker thread, which is not a problem in the primary thread.

I am using IIS7 integrated mode without impersonation, although I got the same results with impersonation in classic mode.

The problem is almost identical to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120404/problem-accessing-file-from-different-thread-in-asp-net), only I have no Response.Redirect and see no applicable fix in the accepted answer.

**EDIT:** I need to solve this without reconfiguring server permissions.  Adequate permissions are already in place, and I have no access to this on the target machine anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give the IIS_WPG group access to your logfile.

Your request probably runs with the account you defined for 'anonymous access' while to worker thread runs as 'network service'.