# Why is Log4Net not recording log statements in my separate thread?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, log4net

I have all of my log4net appenders all setup and working fine within my web application, but when I set off a different thread to start a data sync process, all log statements within that separate thread go into the empty abyss; none of my appenders are fired. Anyone have a clue why that would be?

```
private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger("mylog");

public static string SomeValue
{
  get
  {
    Log.Debug("This WILL be appended to the log");

    var thread = new Thread(SyncData);
    thread.Start();

    return "the value";
  }
}

private static void SyncData()
{
  Log.Debug("This will NOT be appended to log");

  var newLog = LogManager.GetLogger("mylog");
  newLog.Debug("This will also NOT be appended to the log");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should enable Log4net internal debugging and see if log4net is reporting something going wrong.

Check out the "How do I enable log4net internal debugging?" section in [this link](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html).

Comment: This helped point the way to the problem. One of my appenders was relying on `HttpContext.Current`, and what makes perfect sense in hindsight is that HttpContext.Current is NULL in new threads spawned off of the web application thread.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution, could be impersonate all the manualy created threads using the creator's identity as shown in this post: [Thread Not Working in AspNet when deployed to IIS](http://codemine.net/post/Thread-Not-working-in-Aspnet-When-deployed-to-IIS.aspx)

I hope this be very useful like it was to me!

Alejandro.

Answer (score 0):

When you Spawn a new a new Thread in an ASP.Net application it will run under the username of the App Pool (New threads have the same security context as the process that is running your web app, ie the AppPool).  Whereas the the webApp Thread that is currently processing your page may be is running under a different user account; the one that you are impersonating or the account that you defined to run under anonymous access.  The reason for this security difference between the thread IIS gives you and any threads you create is:

We have a single app pool (running under a single account) that is may be processing a number of web requests via separate threads all running under different accounts.  When you create a thread from from within a thread it .'. takes the security of the parent process not the parent thread.

You have two choices, you will either need to give additional permissions to the user account that is set to run the app pool, so you have write permissions to anything you need to log to:

[Thread permissions in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778606/thread-permissions-in-asp-net)

or in theory you could use impersonation on each spawned thread so it has the same security context of the thread it originated from.

http://www.justskins.com/forums/impersonation-in-a-sub-34034.html

Comment: I just tried to quickly debug it to see what users and security context the two threads were running under:

`var user = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;` This yielded the same for both threads... Are you sure that all threads under the w3wp process are not necessarily running under the same user?

Comment: My apologies I swear I saw this behavior in the past as I had similar issues.  Perhaps this only applies to IIS6 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms526063(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: I was hoping you were right on :) But it looks as if the security context is the same for both. I know that you can define the number of processes you want to handle the app pool, of which this application is only set to one. Maybe security becomes more of an issue with multiple processes handling the web application

Comment: Ditto, saw your question and jumped on it I was that sure as something very similar hit me years ago.  But what you see is what you see.  Good luck.